# Where are recognizers for media types stored and how to add one?

Tags: mime-types

When one writes a html file, linux can state that the MIME-type is text/html. How is this handled? Where are the "recognizers" stored? How can one add a MIME type with with an implemented recognizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 libraries that normally handle this. The [shared-mime-info](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info/) library is the big one. However there is also the [file](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) utility which provides 'libmagic'.

Each of these maintains their own database. However the shared-mime-info one is more common, and is designed to be extensible.

As for how to add an entry, the location on my system is `/usr/share/mime`, though it can vary by distro. Basically you just add an xml file in there which explains how to identify your file format (on my system, packages place their files in `/usr/share/mime/packages`).
After you've added your xml file, use the `update-mime-database` command to regenerate the cache.
*(There is a nice tutorial available on the shared-mime-info project site: http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor/)*

Their example file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="image/png">
         <comment xml:lang="en">PNG image</comment>
         <comment xml:lang="af">png beeld</comment>
         ...
         <magic priority="50">
                <match type="string" value="\x89PNG" offset="0"/>
         </magic>
         <glob pattern="*.png"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

---

General resources such as the full specification of the xml file is best obtained from the project site as well: http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/

Comment: There's also /etc/mime.types, but I think this is related to mailcap.

Comment: @slm yeah, I'm not sure what uses `/etc/mime.types`. It only contains the mime names and the file extensions, not enough to identify all types of files. The libmagic and shared-mime-info databases also identify based on the content of the file.

Comment: That file is part of the mailcap package. From RPM desc.: "The mailcap file is used by the metamail program.  Metamail reads the
mailcap file to determine how it should display non-text or multimedia
material.  Basically, mailcap associates a particular type of file
with a particular program that a mail agent or other program can call
in order to handle the file.  Mailcap should be installed to allow
certain programs to be able to handle non-text files."