# `file` doesn’t show proper mime-type for .m2ts files

Tags: mime-types, file-command

I need to define mime type of various video files and I got a problem with [.m2ts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.m2ts) files. Before I stumbled on this, I used `file` utility with `-iL` keys and parsed the output with `sed`. Today I found that `file` 5.15 defines mime type of .m2ts files as ‘application/octet-stream’. O-okay, I updated the package and now it calls them just ‘binary’. When I expected video/something.

Reading about utilities doing similar job, I’ve tried `xdg-mime query filetype`. The problem with `xdg-mime` is that it looks only at the extension of the file. It defines .m2ts as ‘video/mp2t’, but shows it for any, even an empty text file with such extension.

Maybe it was correct to call .m2ts files a stream because it is actually a stream, but then why in the mime database the extension is bound to ‘video/mp2t’?

```
$ grep m2ts /usr/share/mime/video/mp2t.xml
  <glob pattern="*.m2ts"/>
```

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103955/4358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to link provided by @Patrick I understood that `file` has nothing to do with `shared-mime-info` and its database is in /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc. So I googled  for a `~/.magic` file with a fix and found it [here](http://mx.gw.com/pipermail/file/2012/000937.html). The lines there are lacking spaces so I adduce it here

```
4 byte 0x47
>5 beshort 0x4000
>>7 byte ^0xF
>>>196 byte 0x47
>>>>388 byte 0x47
>>>>>580 byte 0x47 M2TS MPEG transport stream, v2
!:mime video/MP2T
```

Answer (score 0):

`.m2ts` is used for multiplexing audio, video and other streams, based on `MPEG-2 transport stream container`.

[RFC 3555](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3555.txt) defined many `MIME subtypes` for MPEG-2 transport stream, include `video/mp2t`. So I think it is normal when it is bounded to `video/mp2t`.

Comment: It is normal, but how to force the `file` to show appropriate mime-type?